# How Can I Revise a List Node Property Using Cypher?

Tags: neo4j, cypher

I have nodes in my graph that contain properties that are of type double[]. How can I do something like this in cypher?

```
for (int i=0; i < theArray.length(); i++)
    theArray[i] *= .8;
```

This obviously doesn't work, but here is the general idea:

```
start a = node(0)
a.theArray = a.theArray*.8
return a;
```

Comment: By `List` do you mean Array, because from what I can remember arrays are allowed as properties, but not Objects, such as Lists.

So you have nodes, which have a property that is an array of doubles? or do you want to test if there are doubles in this array and cast them accordingly?

Comment: I'm sorry, ya I meant Array.  I have nodes which have a property that is an array of doubles and I want to be able to recast them.

Comment: Thank you for clearing up the question. Are you looking to have cypher actually update the nodes, or just send them to you with the difference values? The latest Milestone of Cypher allows updates to the DB.

Comment: Yes I'd like to have Cypher update the nodes.  Also as a side question is there a way to return the values not as an ExecutionResult but as the primitive type they are stored as? Thanks for the quick response.

Comment: The `ExecutionEngine` will return it as an `ExecutionResult`, which can be iterated through to get the `Nodes` which have the property. As for the question about updating in Cypher, You'd have to use the latest version of it, which is still a SNAPSHOT, so it's not ready for production yet. Other then that, I do not believe you can do a pure mathematical operation in cypher.

Comment: I think I'll just return the 'Nodes' then use '.getProperty' and '.setProperty' to do what I want.  Thanks for the answers!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `extract` for that which is like `map` and creates a new collection.

```
start n=node(0) 
set n.foo=extract(x in [1,2,3] : x*0.8)
return n

set n.foo = extract(x in n.foo : x*0.8)
```